# Speed up Flatten[] of a large nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I have a large jagged list, that is each sub-list has a different length.  I would like to `Flatten` this list for `Histogram` purposes, but it seems to be taking an inordinate amount of time and memory

```
jaggedList=Table[RandomReal[1,RandomSample[Range[400000,800000],1]],{n,100}];
```

Just to illustrate, length of each of elements of the main list

```
ListPlot[Length/@jaggedList]
```

[image: list lengths]

Full Flatten takes a long time, my real data is several times larger, it gets painfully slow

```
fullFlatten=Flatten@jaggedList;//AbsoluteTiming
{10.0055,Null}
```

I noticed flattening non-jagged sub-lists is not a problem

```
partialFlatten=Flatten/@jaggedList;//AbsoluteTiming
{0.289219,Null}
```

Memory usage is huge on the final result of the full list, even though number of elements is the same:

```
ByteCount/@{fullFlatten,partialFlatten,jaggedList}
{1460378864,486808224,486808224}
```

Would super appreciate any tips on what I can change to make this faster / more memory compact !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Apply`ing `Join` is much faster than `Flatten`:

```
SeedRandom[1]
jaggedList = Table[RandomReal[1, RandomSample[Range[400000, 800000], 1]], {n, 100}];

fullFlatten = Flatten@jaggedList; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 8.2375848

```
fullFlatten2 = Join @@ jaggedList; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.29729

```
fullFlatten2 == fullFlatten
```

> True

```
ByteCount /@ {fullFlatten, fullFlatten2, jaggedList}
```

> {1462957016, 487652456, 487667608}

Comment: Super appreciate it, that's exactly what I needed ! Now just to speed up the Histogram!

Answer (score 20):

The difference between using [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten) and using [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join) as in @kglr's answer is that [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten) unpacks. Here is a smaller example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = Table[RandomReal[1, RandomSample[2;;5, 1]], 3]
```

> {{0.269558, 0.445678, 0.158104, 0.751213, 0.965444}, {0.0518202, 0.675946, 
>     0.698472}, {0.344389, 0.830322, 0.556863}}

Turn on packing messages:

```
On["Packing"]
```

Then, using [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten):

```
Flatten[list]
```

> Developer`FromPackedArray::unpack: Unpacking array in call to HoldForm.
>
> Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack: Unpacking array with dimensions {5} in call to Flatten.
>
> Developer`FromPackedArray::unpack: Unpacking array in call to HoldForm.
>
> Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack: Unpacking array with dimensions {3} in call to Flatten.
>
> Developer`FromPackedArray::unpack: Unpacking array in call to HoldForm.
>
> General::stop: Further output of Developer`FromPackedArray::unpack will be suppressed during this calculation.
>
> Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack: Unpacking array with dimensions {3} in call to Flatten.
>
> General::stop: Further output of Developer`FromPackedArray::punpack will be suppressed during this calculation.
>
> {0.269558, 0.445678, 0.158104, 0.751213, 0.965444, 0.0518202, 0.675946, 
>   0.698472, 0.344389, 0.830322, 0.556863}

and using [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join):

```
Join @@ list
```

> {0.269558, 0.445678, 0.158104, 0.751213, 0.965444, 0.0518202, 0.675946, 
>   0.698472, 0.344389, 0.830322, 0.556863}

As you can see, using [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join) generates no unpacking messages, which is why it is much faster.

Comment: Appreciate the point about packing, this is helping me troubleshoot more!