# Efficient computation of list mapping

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, number-representation

I'm wondering about possible techniques to solve the following problem efficiently in Mathematica. Suppose you are given a list of integers that represent digits of a number with base 40. This list should be translated into digits with base 253, i.e., each 3 digits with base 40 should be translated into 2 digits with base 253. A simple solution is as follows.

```
l = RandomInteger[{0, 39}, 10000000];
Flatten@Map[IntegerDigits[#, 253] &, 
            Map[FromDigits[#, 40] &,
                Partition[l, 3, 3, {1, 1}, {}]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
{5.16098, Null}
```

As an additional complication suppose the digits with base 253 should be permuted according to a given permutation `f`. Again this can simply be solved by

```
MapIndexed[(f[#2[[1]]] = #1) &, RandomSample[Range[0, 252]]];
Map[f[#] &,
    Flatten@Map[IntegerDigits[#, 253] &, 
                Map[FromDigits[#, 40] &, 
                    Partition[l, 3, 3, {1, 1}, {}]]]]; // AbsoluteTiming
{7.46978, Null}
```

How can the performance be improved in both cases?

**Update 1**

Minor improvement after combining the functions.

```
Flatten@Map[IntegerDigits[FromDigits[#, 40], 253] &, 
            Partition[l, 3, 3, {1, 1}, {}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
{4.32367, Null}
```

**Update 2**

Motivated by MarcoB's answer, I came up with one slight improvement by instantiating IntegerDigits, i.e.

```
Join @@ Map[{Quotient[#, 253], Mod[#, 253]} &, 
             Partition[l, 3].{1600, 40, 1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
{1.37657, Null}
```

Comment: I don't know how much the following will help, but: 1) You don't need to Map twice, you can just map the combined function. 2) as far as I can see, `Partition[l, 3, 3, {1, 1}, {}]` is the same as `Partition[l, 3]`; the latter is unlikely to be faster, but it certainly is more readable.

Comment: Combining both functions yields a worse performance on my machine. The semantics of `Partition[l, 3]` is not the same as `Partition[l, 3, 3, {1, 1}, {}]`. Take `l` to be a list where the number of elements is not a multiple of 3.

Comment: Can you share the "combined function" code that yielded that worse result?

Comment: Good point. I made a mistake. The performance after combining the functions `IntegerDigits[FromDigits[#, 40], 253]` is about the same. A little better but no significant improvement.

Comment: `IntegerDigits` is `Listable` so you do not need to map it onto a list, you can just apply it, which may be faster. See if this makes a difference then: `Flatten@IntegerDigits[
  FromDigits[#, 40]& /@ Partition[l, 3, 3, {1, 1}, {}], 253]`

Comment: This does not improve the performance unfortunately. Still nice.

Comment: Markus, out of curiosity, what do you need this for? It seems an odd process. I wonder if there might not be a completely different approach to the actual underlying problem that could speed things up.

Comment: It is an example of an encoding problem like Base64 or ASCII85. I wonder how this can be made efficient in Mathematica.

Comment: The consider explaining your problem in those terms, rather than asking about your intermediate solution. I am afraid that you may have generated an ["XY problem"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: There is no difference except for different bases and technical details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me introduce one condition, namely that the list's length be an exact multiple of 3. This means that all partitions are exactly 3-long and allows us to use `Dot` instead of `FromDigits`. It's not absolutely necessary, but it may only introduce a small preliminary step and it seems a small price to pay.

The result from your original code for comparison:

```
l = RandomInteger[{0, 39}, 9999999];

(original = 
    Flatten@ 
      Map[IntegerDigits[#, 253] &, 
        Map[FromDigits[#, 40] &, 
          Partition[l, 3, 3, {1, 1}, {}]]]); // RepeatedTiming

(* Out: {10.5, Null} *)
```

Here's my best so far:

```
(withJoin = 
    Join @@ IntegerDigits[
               Partition[l, 3].{1600, 40, 1}, 
               253
            ]
); // RepeatedTiming

(* Out: {4.61, Null} *)
```

This is a better than twofold speedup.

The most significant speedup came from using [`Apply[Join]` instead of `Flatten`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184576/27951): the latter was responsible for *almost half* the time it took the original to run!

Using `Dot` instead of `FromDigits` is also a significant improvement; as is using the `Listable` attribute of `IntegerDigits`, avoiding a `Map` operation.

Of course, the results are the same:

```
original == withJoin               (* Out: True *)
```

Comment: Nice speedup indeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Flatten@BlockMap[IntegerDigits[FromDigits[#, 40], 253] &, l, 3]
```

Not as much faster as I expected, but a bit.

Comment: Thanks for this version. On my machine however, the code below "Update 1" performs slightly better. As you said, there is not much difference in terms of performance.