# Basic manipulations with lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have a list of the following form:

```
List={{{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i}},{{j,k,l},{m,n,o},{p,q,r}}}
```

I have two questions:

A) How can I convert this to a list of the following form:

```
Newlist={{a,b,c},{d,e,f},{g,h,i},{j,k,l},{m,n,o},{p,q,r}}
```

B) How can I access, say, the elements `a`,`d`,`g`,`j`,`m`,`p`?

This is probably a very basic question but I do not have previous experience with Mathematica.

Thank you,

Comment: Look at Flatten. To accomplish your task you will need to flatten at the right level. To access within lists, look at Part, shortcut [[ ]].

Comment: Flatten works! thank you. However, When I use part, can I return a list of all first elements all at once?

Comment: Yes... see All, so something like: list[[All,2]] or list[[2,All]] depending on which ones you want.

Comment: Suppose I want to select elements such that the last coordinate (i.e. c,f,i, etc) are less than some specified value. I can't get All to work here. I know I can use Select, but I don't seem to know the way to do this

Comment: @mathematicastudent you'll need `Select` or `Cases` for that. See also [this tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionalOperations.html#5821).

Answer (score 7):

The word `List` is systemically reserved. (At least in version 11.3) You will see an error message if you use `List` as a variable name.

So, let

```
Lit = {{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}, {{j, k, l}, {m, n, o}, {p, q, r}}}
```

Then my answer is

A) `Lit[[1]] will produce {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}`

B) `List[[1]][[2]][[2]]` will produce `e`

`[[n]]` means `n`-th object in the list.

And.. this is my first answer in stackexchange!

Answer (score 7):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

list = {{{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}, {{j, k, l}, {m, n, o}, {p, q, r}}};

Flatten[list, 1]

(* {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j, k, l}, {m, n, o}, {p, q, r}} *)
```

To get `{a, d, g, j, m, p}` use either

```
First /@ Flatten[list, 1]

(* {a, d, g, j, m, p} *)
```

or

```
list[[All, All, 1]] // Flatten

(* {a, d, g, j, m, p} *)
```

or

```
Flatten[list][[1 ;; ;; 3]]

(* {a, d, g, j, m, p} *)
```

or

```
Map[First, list, {2}] // Flatten

(* {a, d, g, j, m, p} *)
```

**EDIT:** To find x values for maximum z

```
SeedRandom[1234];
list = RandomInteger[10, {20, 3}]

(* {{0, 6, 9}, {6, 10, 0}, {7, 0, 0}, {8, 4, 4}, {8, 5, 9}, {7, 2, 
  8}, {4, 5, 8}, {6, 1, 6}, {1, 2, 0}, {10, 3, 6}, {6, 0, 7}, {4, 3, 
  7}, {9, 6, 6}, {0, 2, 2}, {3, 8, 4}, {1, 4, 2}, {4, 6, 1}, {5, 0, 
  6}, {3, 2, 6}, {8, 3, 3}} *)

First /@ MaximalBy[list, Last]

(* {0, 8} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm also struggling to understand how to get the x coordinate when the z coordinate is a maximum. Any idea how to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For your first question:

```
Catenate@list
```

> {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j, k, l}, {m, n, o}, {p, q, r}}

For your second question:

```
(Catenate@list)[[All,1]]
```

or

```
Transpose[Catenate@list][[1]]
```

both give

> {a, d, g, j, m, p}

Comment: Also `Join@@list`, of course (see also [The difference between using Flatten and using Join](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/184578/106)) by Carl Woll